# What's the meaning of "don't let them get you.'?

Tags: colloquial-language

Folks,

http://nypost.com/2017/06/30/trump-scolds-korean-media-for-wreaking-havoc-in-oval-office/

In the above link, there are sentences as follows;

> But then he turned to his South Korean counterpart and said, “It’s
>   actually a very friendly press, don’t let them get you, although we
>   just lost a table.”

And I cannot clearly understand the meaning of 'don’t let them get you'. Would you please let me know?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is "getting to me" it means that they have found out what causes me to become annoyed or irritated, and are doing exactly that.

"Don't let them get to you" means "Don't let them make you annoyed" He is saying that the press are being irritating, but the Korean premier should not be visibly annoyed.

The expression is casual, conversational, and easiest to understand in context.

Comment: He didn't say *get to you* but *get you*. Nevertheless, sense 27 of the verb in [the OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get) is the same as described in this answer.